# TSocket read 0 bytes - happybase version 0.8

Tags: python, hbase, thrift, happybase

I'm trying to connect hbase by happybase framework version 0.8.

I've started daemon thrift - 
`/usr/hdp/current/hbase-master/bin/hbase-daemon.sh start thrift -p 9090`

```
 from happybase.connection import Connection
 DEFAULT_HOST = '10.128.121.13'
 DEFAULT_PORT = 9090
 DEFAULT_TRANSPORT = 'framed'
 DEFAULT_COMPAT = '0.96'`

 cc = Connection(DEFAULT_HOST,DEFAULT_PORT,None,True,None,'_',DEFAULT_COMPAT,DEFAULT_TRANSPORT) print(cc.tables())`
```

Do I need to start thrift service in all nodes, Hbase master and RegionServers ?

I got this error:

> TSocket read 0 bytes

Answer (score 2):

If it is a distributed cluster, you don't have to run thrift server of each node individually.

It seems to be issue with instantiation of Connection.   Try following :

`conn = happybase.Connection( host='DEFAULT_HOST', port='DEFAULT_PORT', protocol='compact' )`

You can also have a look in this issue : https://github.com/wbolster/happybase/issues/193